# How do I convert this data from long to wide using dcast in R?

Tags: r, reshape, dcast

Trying to reformat my data from long to wide.

Starting out with:

```
head(rna.dat)
     sample_barcode gene_name HTSeq__Counts
1: TCGA-CS-4938-01B     KRT17             8
2: TCGA-CS-4938-01B     SMAD2          6123
3: TCGA-CS-4938-01B      BRAF          1512
4: TCGA-CS-4938-01B   ANKRD61            16
5: TCGA-CS-4938-01B      MTOR          6474
6: TCGA-CS-4938-01B      EXOG           582
```

Then I run:

```
rna.wide=dcast.data.table(rna.dat,sample_barcode~gene_name,value.var="HTSeq__Counts")

Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
```

...which outputs:

```
     sample_barcode A1BG A1CF A2M A2ML1
1: TCGA-CS-4938-01B    1    1   1     1
2: TCGA-CS-4942-01A    1    1   1     1
3: TCGA-CS-4943-01A    1    1   1     1
4: TCGA-CS-5393-01A    1    1   1     1
5: TCGA-CS-5396-01A    1    1   1     1
```

... i.e. the count values are being filled with 1's.

For example, the value in position [1,1] should be 36:

```
rna.dat[rna.dat$sample_barcode=="TCGA-CS-4938-01B" & rna.dat$gene_name=="A1BG",]
     sample_barcode gene_name HTSeq__Counts
1: TCGA-CS-4938-01B      A1BG            36
```

In the past I've used 'reshape' with success, but this data has some 4 million rows, and never seems to finish. dcast works in a matter of seconds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `dcast.data.table` is using an aggregate function, that probably means you have some duplicate gene name / barcode pairs in your data. Remove the duplicates, or set `fun.aggregate = sum` or `mean` if you want to add or average the counts from duplicate groupings.

Comment: Does this work? `dcast.data.table(rna.dat,sample_barcode~gene_name + rowid(sample_barcode),value.var="HTSeq__Counts")`

Comment: @GregorThomas That did the trick -- thank you so much! I've never encountered I() before either, so that's good to know.

Comment: @RonakShah That worked as well! I also did not know about rowid(), but have needed a function like this on many occasions. Thank you!

Comment: `I()` is most commonly used in model formulas if you want to actually transform a variable. `y ~ (a + b)^2` will give `a` and `b` and the interaction term `a:b`, `y ~ I((a + b)^2` will add `a` and `b` together and square it, and use that as a feature.